# How to get json value with jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
String url = "https://ko.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srprop=sectiontitle&srlimit=1&srsearch=grand-theft-auto-v";

String test = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

Map<String, String> testToJson = objectMapper.readValue(test, Map.class);
```

`testToJson` is:

```
{
    batchcomplete: "",
    continue: {
        sroffset: 1,
        continue: "-||",
    },
    query: {
        searchinfo: {
            totalhits: 12
        },
        search: [
            {
                ns: 0,
                title: "그랜드 테프트 오토 V",
                pageid: 797633,
            }
        ],
    },
}
```

I want to get `title` value.

I try

```
testToJson.get("title")
```

but it returns null.

How to get `title` value with jackson?

Answer (score 3):

You can deserialise it to a `JsonNode` and use `JSON Pointer` to get required field:

```
JsonNode node = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, JsonNode.class);
String title = node.at("/query/search/0/title").asText();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could build a class for this json result then read from it.

```java
public class Result {
  private JsonNode searchinfo;
  private JsonNode[] searches;
}
// then read:
Result testToJson = objectMapper.readValue(test, Result.class);
System.out.println(testToJson.getSearches(0).get("title"));
```

[refer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-mapping-dynamic-object)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to read JSON into an instance of a generic class like that because the info about generics are used in compile time and already lost when program is running.

Jackson captures the data about generics using a sub-classed instance of `TypeReference<T>`.

```java
Map<String, String> testToJson = objectMapper.readValue(test, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});
```

The problem with this approach is that `Map<String, String>` almost never describes complex data (like in the example) correctly. The example contains not only string values, there are numbers and even nested objects.

In situations like that, when you don't want or cannot write a class that describes the structure of the JSON, the better choice is parsing the JSON into a tree structure and traverse it. For example:

```java
JsonNode node = objectMapper.readTree(test);
String title = node.get("query").get("search").get(0).get("title").asText();
Integer offset = node.get("continue").get("strOffset").asInt()
```

Comment: Jackson can read into a tree of `Maps` and `Lists` just fine. It's just not a `Map<String, String>` like in the OP, but a `Map<String, Object>`